# temporary link / url for the attachments of an issue in jira cloud instance

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

JIRA provides a way to access the attachments of an issue using basic auth, jwt auth mechanisms. Using which we can download those files. We're able to download the files using both authentication mechanisms.

sample jwt auth:

curl -X GET --url https://{site-name}.atlassian.net/secure/attachment/1001/example.txt -H 'Authorization: jwt '

**Issue / Our requirement:**

But is there a way to generate temporarily accessible url for the JIRA issue's attachments which will have token embedded into the URI itself. I've added the example of that below

example url:

https://{site-name}.atlassian.net/attachment/1001/example.txt?token={temp_access_token}

While accessing / clicking on the above mentioned url the download should automatically start even if the user isn't logged into their account

**Reason for our requirement:**

We're creating jira cloud based service / app and one of its feature is providing access to the user's attachments through our application. Our limitation(cloud service cost) is that we can't download all the huge sized attachments and store and manage it. So we're looking for a solution using which user's can download from the JIRA's server directly

Answer (score 0):

In your JWT generation steps, you can define how long the JWT should be valid. And you can attach a JWT to the URL like this: `<Jira Base Url>/rest/api/3/...?jwt=...`. This way, you could generate a JWT on demand and it'll only be valid for the given time that you define.

In the **Java Example** on the page [Understanding JWT for Connect apps](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/understanding-jwt/) you can see how they are setting the `expirationTime`. Just do the same, on demand. Here is the important part of the code snippet:

```
public class JWTSample {

    public String createUriWithJwt()
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        long issuedAt = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
        long expiresAt = issuedAt + 180L;

        /* ... */

        JwtJsonBuilder jwtBuilder = new JsonSmartJwtJsonBuilder()
                .issuedAt(issuedAt)
                .expirationTime(expiresAt)
                .issuer(key);

        /* ... */

        String jwtToken = /* ... */;

        String apiUrl = baseUrl + apiPath + "?jwt=" + jwtToken;
        return apiUrl;
    }
}
```

**Security concern:** I'm explicitly mentioning that you should generate these links on demand because you should not set the expiration date to more than 5-10 minutes (which is already quite high). Otherwise an attacker just needs to retrieve your generated link (URLs are often logged somewhere) and is also able to retrieve the attachment as well.

**Alternative Approach**

Since you mentioned you'll build a service/app, why not chain the attachment download through your service? This way you wouldn't have to expose a JWT which is a potential security threat. For example: you offer a download button in your UI, this sends a HTTP request to your service and your service downloads the attachment and then forwards it to your user. However, this would not comply with your requirement to give access to unauthenticated users - if that's really what you want to do.